# Removing a part of a string with double quote [R]

Tags: r, substring

I have the following string:

```
x<-"\"stream;\"\" Well done\"\t\"  fans !!\"\";\"\"Boy\""
```

and I woould like to change it to

```
   x= "\"stream;\"\" Well done fans !!\"\";\"\"Boy\""
```

would be great if anyone could help me removing `\"\t\"` from this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(from comment) You can use

```
sub("\"\t\"","",x)
```

That removes exactly what you're asking to be removed (though there is still an extra space compared to your desired output)